# How can I move branch files from an old repository to a new one without the old commits

Tags: git, branch, multiple-repositories

I am creating a new pristine repository for the next generation of our product. I need to use some "state" from the old repo -- similar to cherry-picking. In fact, functionally it would be simply resetting to a commit on the old repo then committing the file changes to the new repository. I did find that I could checkout the old branch, reset --soft to the earliest commit, then commit those files. But it seems like a hack. Since I see upstream and origin as a bit of a pattern, it seems like this would not be too uncommon, although I guess most of those cases would want commits.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a checkout --orphan so that you go to that revision (working tree content) but have no history behind it. When you do your first commit, it will be a root commit, no history behind it.

```
git checkout ---orphan -b new-branch some-revision-to-get-working-tree
```

Comment: I upvoted because it does handle the initial commit scenario. But this does not help after you have the files in the new repo. With orphan, you get all of the files with no commit history and that was what I initially asked for. But what I really want is to checkout a branch (let's say next-build) with the new repo's limited commit history then grab the files from a specific commit in the upstream. Those files would then be seen as changed or added in the new repo branch. I have found some other ways to handle this; e.g. upstream as a submodule.